# Using MySQL Data Reader

Tags: c#, mysql, datareader

I'm not familiar with using Data Reader, i need help with the following code, i want to retrieve a single data from the database.

```
MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    conn.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    data.Fill(dt);
                    gridView1.DataSource = dt;

                    int retrievedValue = 0;
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if ((int)reader["order_status"] == 0)
                            {
                                retrievedValue = (int)reader.GetValue(0);

                                    GridView View2 = sender as GridView;
                                    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                                    e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.ForestGreen;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `order_status` column? Also you need to use `==` for equality checking, `=` is assignment operator.

Comment: It contains a numeric values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 its an INT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reader["order_status"]` returns `object`, since you told it is an *already* integer, you need to cast it to `int` first.

You need to use [`==` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) as well since it is a equality operator. [`=` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) is an assignment operator.

```
if ((int)reader["order_status"] == 0)
```

Or you can use [`GetInt32` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with it's *zero-based* column number. Let's say it's the first column that your query returns, you can use it like;

```
if(reader.GetInt32(0) == 0)
```

By the way, if you wanna get only single value, I *strongly* suspect you may wanna use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method since it get's the first column of the first row. Then you can structure your query as `SELECT order_status FROM ...` etc..

Comment: @KevinRodriguez If value that you want to get is the first column of the first row, you can use `ExecuteScalar` method like, `int value = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`. Remember, your query _can_ get multiple rows with multiple columns. This does not break this methods. `ExecuteScalar` method gets first column of the first row and other values in your command are ignored.

Comment: im not getting this right, the code wont let me retrieve rows that has a value of 0?

Comment: What is your `cmd` query exactly? You will not need `ExecuteReader` when you use `ExecuteScalar` by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to assign a variable before `while (reader.Read())` otherwise it will and error. Then close the data reader once you are finished using it. Like so:

```
 using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())    
    {

    int retrievedValue = 0;

          while (reader.Read())
          {
                retrievedValue = (int)reader.GetValue(0);
                if (retrievedValue == 0)
                {

                    GridView View2 = sender as GridView;
                                    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                                    e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.ForestGreen;
                }
                else if (retrievedValue == 1)
                {

                    GridView View2 = sender as GridView;
                                    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                                    e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.ForestGreen;
                }
          }//and so on...
          reader.Close();
    }
```

I hope this is was you're looking for.

Comment: thank you, will this code retrieve rows that has a value of 0?

Comment: Which column number do you want to retrieve data from? If you want to retrieve from the first column then use `retrievedValue = dr.GetValue(0)` or from second column, `retrievedValue = dr.GetValue(1)`, etc. Note that it will only use 1 row but you must specify which column you want in dr.GetValue.

Comment: You may also need to convert data to a data type such as: `Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0));` but for strings, you do not: `dr.GetString(0)`

Comment: order_status column, it has a value of ranging from 1 - 6, and if the value of a row is 1 i need to paint the gridview row to red and if it is 2 need to paint it with green and so on. im getting an error  Could not find specified column in results: order_status

Comment: The error is likely caused by misspellings in your query. Make sure that your column names, tables, etc are correctly spelled.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of `(reader["order_status"] ==0` is. If you are trying to find 0 in "order_status" then I would add 'WHERE order_status = 0' to my SQL query and replace the if statement with `if (reader.Read() == 0)` and delete `retrievedValue = dr.GetValue(X)` I will update my answer.